# Custom keyboard buttons iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

I am trying to setup a highlighted state for keyboard buttons, but have some difficulties with it:

1. I can't set `backgroundImage` to be beneath the `spaceButton Image`, so it won't overlap `shift_1` like on the image below (button is tapped).
2. I can't set up layer margins, so that there would be a space from the bottom and other buttons, and at the same time that spacing would function as that button.

Below is my code:

```
[self.spaceButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shift_1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.spaceButton setBackgroundImage:[KeyboardViewController imageFromColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4 alpha:0.5]]
                                        forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            self.spaceButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0;
            self.spaceButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I would be very thankful if anyone could help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You would have two ways:**

**By Image** : Just add transparent pixel at bottom,left,right in image and create new image then set that image as in background image of button.

**By `imageEdgeInsets`** : Set button `imageEdgeInsets` and use to `image` property for set image(Highlighted/Normal state).